# ubuntu 14.04 64bit on Virtualbox Windows 10 host

Tags: virtualbox

I installed the latest version of Virtualbox on a Windows 10 guest laptop, and when selecting the 'Create Virtual Machine' menu, it only shows 32-bit options for Linux.

How do I install Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on Virtualbox Windows 10 host?

Comment: I think the Windows 10 is actually the host. The guest is the operating system you install in the virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks @karel for spotting the duplicate. I didn't find it when I did my search, now I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to enable Virtualization in BIOS, if your CPU support it. Else you are stuck with 32 bit guests.

Comment: Brilliant, I got it working. Thanks for the super-fast reply.